# Как поставить знак тильды (~) не используя кнопки с тильдой?

Tags: клавиатура

Как любого рода сочетанием клавиш поставить знак тильды, если у меня на тильду поставлен другой функционал? (в моем случае переключение клавиатуры)

Например <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>~</kbd> (или другими) поставить тильду `~`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Для того, что бы узнать альтернативное сочетание клавиш на ЛЮБОЙ знак тебе нужно зайти в `"Пуск" => Character Map` и там найти нужный знак.  Там же есть информация о том, как вызвать даный символ. Там будет на тильде написано `U+007E: Tilde`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

`007E` - это номер знака в ASCII таблице, только 16ричный.

Но нам нужен десятичный номер знака, а не шестнадцатеричный. Переводим при помощи инженерного/программерского калькулятора:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

или же ищем при помощи интернета в десятичной системе и получаем: `126`.

Это значит что в виндовсе нужно зажать `Alt` + `набрать ASCII номер` (`126` или `0126`) на цифровой клавиатуре (та что прямоугольная с правой стороны). Вот знак напечатанный этим способом: ~

Comment: спасибо большое!